# Простейшая карусель на jQuery, CSS3

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Я искал пример с кодом карусели на jQuery. Или CSS3... но нашел лишь кучу мусора и мало что по делу... вот тебе и 3Д и что хочешь, а обычной красивой нет)
в общем вот пример http://lpgenerator.ru там в разделе О НАС ГОВОРЯТ нужная мне карусель. как такую сделать. будьте добры ссылку на код)
буду очень благодарен!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть так: http://jsfiddle.net/3t6PB/2/

Comment: у Zelta кишки скрипта зачётные!

Comment: вот, да, хороший пример. только есть пара вопросов.
1. когда я все это дело вставляю на свой сайт, почему то не работает. даже на локальной машине, в чем причина?
2. теги section, article и nav адекватно работают во всех браузерах? почему Вы используете их вместо ДИВов?

Comment: так, жокрутил этот скрипт, все работает как нужно. тупо забыл подключить библиотеку + добавил строчку а ля: $(document).ready(function(){

НО остался вопрос об "теги section, article и nav адекватно работают во всех браузерах? почему Вы используете их вместо ДИВов?"

Comment: Да эти работают отлично во всех современных браузерах и все современные сайты их используют, совсем не стоит их смущаться.

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет метод jquery.animate. Нужно создать див с overflow: hidden, напихать в него контент и анимировать margin [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/aN8zc/).

Comment: не очень понял как это работает, у вас же там только один слайд?

Comment: оно просто двигает один див внутри другого. Так как у первого overflow: hidden, в нем видна только часть второго.

Слайдов несколько, тыкайте на кнопки под каруселью. Если вы про то, что див «screen» только один, то так и должно быть. В него можно напихать квадратных блочных элементов, это могут быть дивы, или, как у меня, картинки.

Comment: Для достижения автоматической прокрутки можно повесить setInterval (http://jsfiddle.net/XAfhH/1/ — обновил свой пример и добавил еще комментариев)